# How to sum a region in excel for specific row and column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum the highlighted regions. That is, a specific range of columns and rows. So for example: The Product 6 in France from week 20233 to 20236.

I want to sum the blue area:

[image]

I tried with SUMIFS(OFFSET(MATCH(week))) and I can sum one week (one column) given the region and product, but I cannot find the way to sum several columns.

Comment: Typo in your screenshot: 20136 <> 20236. That being said, please post markdown sample data for us to copy-paste to our own application.

Answer (score 0):

You need `SUMPRODUCT()`. Try-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$J$25)*($A$2:$A$25=L11)*($B$2:$B$25=M11)*($C$1:$J$1>=20233)*($C$1:$J$1<=20236))
```

[image]